# Creating a Hover effect Menu in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i need to make a slide-out menu , something like the one in these pictures: [image: The menu on the right before hovering on it]

[image: The menu on the right after hovering on one of the menu items]

EDIT: i tried using css but my side-bar wont show up, this is my css code:

```
.SideBar{
position: absolute;
left: -80px;
transition: 0.4s;
width: 80px;
font-size: 15px;
color: white;
transition: 0.3s
```

}
    `.SideBar:hover{
      left: 0;
}`

Comment: show your code, what have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: I haven' t tried anything actually , i really don't know how to approach the topic at hand , can you maybe point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

use OnHover, and then when will be on hover, change state. after change state you can use condititon.

something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>(this.state.isHovered) ? (<a>openedmenu</a>) :(<a onHover={this.hover.bind(this)}>closed menu</a>)</div>
     )
}


hover() {
this.setState({isHovered:true})
}
```

and then you can experiment by your self

Comment: Thank you , i'll continue looking up more information